# Random pages wont load any css files then automatically fix itself?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, iis

I have a website in Asp.net that sometimes don't load up any css files. It happens randomly on certain movies and then fixes itself after couple of hours (I thinking due to re-caching on the server)

For example I have a movie page www.example.com.au/Movie/Mr-Right and www.example.com.au/Movie/Everybody Wants Some

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head><title>
     Dendy Cinemas: Everybody Wants Some 
   </title><meta property="og:type" content="movie" /><meta        property="og:title" content="Dendy Cinemas: Everybody Wants Some " /><meta property="og:url" content="http://www.dendy.com.au/Movie/Everybody-Wants-Some"        /><meta name="keywords" content="Dendy, Dendy Cinemas, Dendy Canberra, Dendy        Opera Quays, Dendy Newtown, Dendy Portside, Dendy Brisbane, Dendy Byron Bay, Session Times, Movies, Ballet, Opera" /><meta name="description" content="A group of college baseball players navigate their way through the freedoms and responsibilities of unsupervised adulthood." /><meta property="og:description" content="A group of college baseball players navigate their way through the freedoms and responsibilities of unsupervised adulthood." /><meta property="og:image" content="http://www.dendy.com.au/SharedContent/4hKMvTS35U6ACDPcViUrqg.jpg" />       </head>
   <body>
       <form name="form1" method="post" action="Everybody-Wants-Some" id="form1">
   <div>
   <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"        value="/wEPDwULLTIwNzE1OTQxODdkZOSb2/BkiFCf2AWGsmI7Mr5F13nl" />
   </div>

   <div>

       <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="5415F9F0" />
   </div>
       <div>
    <h1>
        Dendy Cinemas: Everybody Wants Some 
    </h1>
    <p>
        Rated MA15+, 117 mins.
        Starring Blake Jenner, Tyler Hoechlin, Ryan Guzman .
        A group of college baseball players navigate their way through the freedoms and responsibilities of unsupervised adulthood.
    </p>
    <img src="http://www.dendy.com.au/SharedContent/4hKMvTS35U6ACDPcViUrqg.jpg" title="Everybody Wants Some " />
</div>
</form>
```

First one loads fine with all content but the other loads with less information like title and synopsis
Both pages uses the same movie page and master page with the sites main CSS files. Same aspx page Same code, only different is the movie details in it.

I use IIS 7.5 and checked that "static Content" is installed on the server. I also did some research and found an article that suggested to change the Anonymous Authentication credentials  from "Specific User (IUSR)" to "application pool identity"
I didn't want to make this change as I do know if a restart on IIS is needed which i can't have in peak hours.

is there a fix to this?

Comment: Still happening at times. For example http://www.grandcinemas.com.au/Movie/Rogue-One-A-Star-Wars-Story
sometimes it loads the synopsis and poster without any css or js.
Any other movies titles works fine. Each movie title is handled by the same /movie page routing in asp.net 
However i restart the site on IIS , its back to normal -  very strange

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it turned out that it was due to authentication problem as I had ? in config file which was preventing css to load when user is not authenticated/ logged in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the content of the page is for the public and user does not need to log in? Would it just show a non-css page?